# IronPython: list.append(string) returns None/null

Tags: list, null, append, ironpython, nonetype

I have a function that gets a string from a property in a C# class. If the field is identified as a field that contains a list of strings it is converted to a list with split else it just returns a string.

```
 def GetFieldValue(self, book, strFieldName):
     objReturn = getattr(book, strFieldName)
     if strFieldName in listFields:
         return objReturn.split(', ')
     else:
         return objReturn
```

I have another function that is designed to append a string to the returned value from that function depending on its type

```
def GetAppendedValue(self, book, strFieldName, strAppend):
    objReturn = GetFieldValue(book, strFieldName)
    if strFieldName in listFields:
        return objReturn.append(strAppend)*
    else:
        return objReturn + ' ' + strAppend*
```

Can someone help me figure out why the "***" lines produce a null/None value? The outcome is as expected in every case up until executing these lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
return objReturn.append(strAppend)
```

with:

```
objReturn.append(strAppend)
return objReturn
```

Explanation:
The function `append()` doesn't return anything.

As for why the line:

```
return objReturn + ' ' + strAppend
```

returns null, it probably doesn't - you just don't reach that line during execution.
If you want to make sure, you can replace it with the following:

```
objReturn += ' ' + strAppend
print objReturn
return objReturn
```

Comment: thanks I'm new at python and I'm still used to the C# practices, i would have never figured that out